# How can I expose an underlying type outside a library via an alias?

Tags: f#

I'm writing a PostgreSQL wrapper library for myself and I want to re-export the `NpgsqlDbType` without requiring `Npgsql` to be opened by the library user.
I'm using Rider and it is able to resolve the modules correctly, but when I run the tests with .NET 7 I get a 'module not defined' error (FS0039). How can I re-export an aliased type like this?

I tried exporting it like so:
`type SqlType = NpgsqlDbType`
And Rider resolved the types correctly, but .NET 7 would not compile it.